# NameError: name 'user_data' is not defined

Tags: python

The function I wrote seems to have some problems. I want to use it to block a larger file. When I use it, the variable I defined is undefined.

On Google's colab platform.

```
def get_df2(file):
    mydata2 = []
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(file,chunksize=500000,header = None,sep='\t'):
        mydata2.append(chunk)
    user_data = pd.concat(mydata2,axis=0)
    names2= ['user_id','age','gender','area','status','edu','ConAbility','device','work','CType','behhavior']
    user_data.columns = names2
    return user_data
```

I use my function like this:

```
user_data_path = 'myfile' #The file here is from my cloud, its detailed definition is too long, only abbreviations are given here.
get_df2(user_data_path)
user_data.head()
```

Error is as follows：

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-da7cac3b4241> in <module>()
      1 get_df2(user_data_path)
----> 2 user_data.head()

NameError: name 'user_data' is not defined
```

Can someone help me?Or give me a suggestion

Comment: you havn't defined `user_data` outside of your function, maybe you meant `user_data = get_df2(user_data_path)` or similar

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `user_data`, but not binding it to a name outside your function scope. You need:

```
user_data = get_df2(user_data_path)
```

Comment: Please raise a new problem as a new question.